# Wrong data type in WorksheetFunction.Filter

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

I'm trying to make a function MonstersInLevel() that filters the second column of my "LevelMonsters" named range based on the value of the first column. The range's first column represents a game level ID and the second column represents a monster ID that appears in that level. [Here's what my range looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVWX3.png)

If I call MonstersInLevel(2) I expect the function to return a range consisting of "2", "3" and "4".

```
Function MonstersInLevel(level As Integer) As Range
    MonstersInLevel = Application.WorksheetFunction.Filter(Range("LevelMonsters").Columns(2), Range("LevelMonsters").Columns(1) = level)
End Function
```

I get:

> A value used in the formula is of the wrong data type

I'm using the FILTER function as I would as an Excel formula. I assume there's some difference in the Excel and VBA syntax for FILTER's criteria.

Comment: The problem should be with `Range("LevelMonsters").Columns(1) = level`. If there is an easy solution, declare `level` As Variant. I don't think it's that simple but it has to be tried.

Comment: I just tried it but didn't work... :/

Comment: I don't think `Filter` returns a `Range`. It should return an array. `Range("LevelMonsters").Columns(1) = level` is going to be a `Type Mismatch` too.

Comment: ... this is going to be more complex then you think. The 2nd argument of `Filter` should be a 2D array of Booleans it seems (which makes sense) and the same size as the first argument. So you have to create that array. `Filter` then looks like it returns a `Variant` array.

Comment: This could help. I'll try creating that boolean array then. But I honestly could use any other function, I just need to get a range or an array containing those values, so I can pick one at random later. If you guys know any other VBA function that would be more appropriate than `Application.WorksheetFunction.Filter` I'd be ok.

Answer (score 7):

Just encountered this problem myself and wanted to post my workaround.

We need to return an array of `True`/`False` to the worksheet function.  To do this I created a Function that takes a 2D array, the column wanted and the value to compare.  It then returns a 2d single column array of the necessary `True`/`False`.

```
Function myeval(arr() As Variant, clm As Long, vl As Variant) As Variant()
    Dim temp() As Variant
    ReDim temp(1 To UBound(arr, 1), 1 To 1)
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        temp(i, 1) = arr(i, clm) = vl
    Next i
    
    myeval = temp
End Function
```

So in this particular case it would be called:

```
Function MonstersInLevel(level As Integer) As Variant
    MonstersInLevel = Application.WorksheetFunction.Filter(Range("LevelMonsters").Columns(2), myeval(Range("LevelMonsters").Value, 1, level),"""")
End Function
```

Comment: Nice +:) Same idea, but tried to explain and follow the worksheet logic in my answer without your valid workaround.

Comment: @T.M. I wanted one to deal with 2d arrays, which have no address.  In my specific case I had created variant arrays and filled them with data from multiple worksheets.  That is why I could not use evaluate.

Comment: @QHarr you are correct I missed that, It should return a variant array.

Comment: Friendly hint: suppose the first argument in the `myEval()` function (here: `arr()`) should be *without* **brackets** to allow passing a datafield array (`Range("LevelMonsters").Value`). - IMO the correct coding would be:  `Function myeval(arr As Variant, ...` @ScottCraner

Answer (score 5):

Solution without any supporting VBA function:

```
Function MonstersInLevel(level As Integer) As Variant
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        MonstersInLevel = .Filter(Range("LevelMonsters").Columns(2), _
        .IfError(.XLookup(Range("LevelMonsters").Columns(1), level, True), False))
    End With
End Function
```

XLookup returns an array of `#N/A` or `True`. IfError replaces errors with `False`. Finally, the Filter function receives an array of booleans as the second parameter.

**EDIT**

Removed the `IfError` function thanks to @ScottCraner:

```
Function MonstersInLevel(level As Integer) As Variant
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        MonstersInLevel = .Filter(Range("LevelMonsters").Columns(2), _
        .XLookup(Range("LevelMonsters").Columns(1), level, True, False))
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: I know Vlookup and Match error in a way that IfError will not pickup.  I think you will need to use the fourth criterion instead of IfError `.XLookup(Range("LevelMonsters").Columns(1), level, True, False)`

Comment: @ScottCraner Excellent idea! I will edit the answer

Comment: I will test this.  I like it.

Comment: This works, but is slightly slower when using 2D arrays instead or ranges. But definitely easier when working with ranges.

Comment: @ScottCraner I guess you would use something like this for a quick one-time job. I don't tend to mix worksheet functions with VBA anyway for portability and compatibility issues (e.g. not Excel Application) so I tend to push more on the VBA side as in [here](https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-ArrayTools). I just didn't see any other worthwhile answer since your one covers this very well, so I went for an all-in worksheet function approach

Comment: Worth reading how to get over the hurdle to integrate the boolean set as second argument and to trick the dynamic worksheet logic :+)

Answer (score 4):

**Avoid type mismatch in Worksheetfunction via VBA**

> Keeping in mind that the 2nd argument reflects a *dynamic matrix condition*
> based entirely on ►**worksheet logic** (returning an array of 0 or 1 cell values /False or True])
> it seems that you have

- to execute an **evaluation** at least within this argument and
- declare the function type (explicitly or implicitly) as `Variant`

```
Function MonstersInLevel(level As Integer) As Variant
    ''   Failing assignment:
    '    MonstersInLevel = Application.WorksheetFunction.Filter(Range("LevelMonsters").Columns(2), _
    '        Range("LevelMonsters").Columns(1) = level _
    '        )
    MonstersInLevel = Application.WorksheetFunction.Filter( _
                      Range("LevelMonsters").Columns(2), _
                      Evaluate(Range("LevelMonsters").Columns(1).Address & "=" & level) _
                      )
End Function
```

> ...or to evaluate the *complete* function

```
Function MonstersInLevel(level As Integer) As Variant
    Dim expr As String
    expr = "=Filter(" & _
           Range("LevelMonsters").Columns(2).Address & "," & _
           Range("LevelMonsters").Columns(1).Address & "=" & level & _
           ")"
    'Debug.Print expr
    MonstersInLevel = Evaluate(expr)
End Function
```

**Example call writing results to any target**

```
Dim v
v = MonstersInLevel(2)
Sheet1.Range("D2").Resize(UBound(v), UBound(v, 2)) = v
```

*Of course it would be possible as well to write `.Formula2` expressions programmatically, even splitting into spill range references.*

---

### **Addendum** ........... *//as of Jan 10th*

**Backwards compatible workaround via VBA.Filter()**

> *"If you guys know any other VBA function that would be more appropriate
> than `Application.WorksheetFunction.Filter` I'd be ok."*

In order to provide also a *backwards compatible alternative*,
I demonstrate the following approach using the classic (VBA.)`Filter()` function (see section `[3]`) based upon
prior matching results (see `[1]`).

Note that `Application.Match()` comparing *two* (!) array inputs
delivers a whole array of possible findings (instead of a single result as most frequently executed).
Non findings are identified by `IsError()` values of `-1`; adding `+1` results in a set
of zeros and ones. Section `[2]` enters corresponding data for positive findings.
Eventually non-findings (i.e. `0`or zero) are removed by a tricky negative filtering.

**Function `getLevels()`**

```
Function getLevels(rng As Range, ByVal level As Long)
'Site: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65630126/how-to-remove-only-the-duplicate-row-instead-of-removing-all-the-rows-that-follo
    '[0] get datafield array
    Dim v, v2
    v = Application.Index(rng.Value2, 0, 1)     ' 1st column
    v2 = Application.Index(rng.Value2, 0, 2)        ' 2nd column
    '[1] check data (with Match comparing 2 arrays :-)
    Dim results
    results = Application.Transpose(Application.Match(v, Array(level), 0))
    '[2] rebuild with False/True entries
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(results)
        results(i) = IsError(results(i)) + 1        ' 0 or 1-values
        If results(i) Then results(i) = v2(i, 1)    ' get current value if true
    Next i
    '[3] remove zeros (negative filtering)
    results = Filter(results, "0", False)
    '[4] return results as vertical 1-based array
    getLevels = Application.Transpose(results)
End Function
```

**Example call**

```
    Const LVL = 2       ' define level
    With Sheet1                                     ' change to project's sheet Code(Name)
        'define data range (assuming columns A:B)
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = .UsedRange.Resize(, 2)
        'function call getLevels()
        Dim levels
        levels = getLevels(rng, level:=LVL)
        'write to target
        .Columns("I:I").Clear
        .Range("I2").Resize(UBound(levels), 1) = levels
    End With
```

Answer (score 2):

**I couldn't resolve your question** but as I did some testing on the subject trying to do so, I thought I'd share my findings:

Based on [this Microsoft community post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-can-the-result-array-of-the-new-filter/9555a2eb-d0f9-4532-a11a-d2429c3b3feb), or at least the *answers* there, it seems you will need to loop through the output in one way or another...

That question seems to want to achieve the same as what you are wanting to do (I think?).

On the other hand, I have never used the `WorksheetFunction.Filter` method, and the closest I could get it to working was like so:

Here is my sample data - `RangeOne` is **Column A** and `RangeTwo` is **Column B**. I have used the `=FILTER()` function in cell **C1** evaluating the input in **D1** for reference of expected results. Naturally this function is working as expected! The VBA routine is outputting to Columns E, F and G.

[image: Sample worksheet data]

```
Sub TestFilterFunction()
    Dim TestArray As Variant
    
    Range("E1:E3") = Application.Filter(Range("RangeTwo"), Range("RangeOne"), Range("D1"))
    Range("F1:F3") = Application.Filter(Range("RangeTwo"), Range("RangeOne") = Range("D1")) 'Runtime Error 13
    Range("G1:G3") = Application.Filter(Range("RangeTwo"), Range("RangeOne"))
    
    TestArray = Application.Filter(Range("RangeTwo"), Range("RangeOne"), Range("D1"))
    TestArray = Application.Filter(Range("RangeTwo"), Range("RangeOne") = Range("D1"))      'Runtime Error 13
    TestArray = Application.Filter(Range("RangeTwo"), Range("RangeOne"))

    Range("H1:H3") = Application.Filter(Range("RangeTwo", "RangeOne"), Range("RangeOne"), Range("D1"))
    TestArray = Application.Filter(Range("A1:B9"), Range("RangeOne"), "2")

End Sub
```

Column E returned the first 3 values from `RangeTwo`.
Column F has not been populated - This is because that line threw the `Runtime error 13 - Type Mismatch`
Column G returned the first 3 values from `RangeTwo`.
Column H returned the first 3 values from "A1:B9" (both ranges together) - specifically the first 3 values of column A.

I thought this was odd so I threw in an array to assign the values to rather than directly to the worksheet;

The first `TestArray` line and the third `TestArray` line both populated the array with the entire `RangeTwo` values;

[image: Locals window showing how the test array was populated]

I realised with the syntax of the first and third attempt at the `WorksheetFunction.Filter`, the entire range is returned (that being the first argument - *Arg1* -  range), but when trying to include the  `= Range("D1")` , it returns the `Type Mismatch` error.

The final `TestArray` attempt being the same syntax as the Column H test, returned both columns in a 2D array (now `TestArray(1 To 9, 1 To 2)`).

I should note I couldn't find any documentation at all on `WorksheetFunction.Filter` so I'm assuming it does follow the same syntax as the Excel Sheet Function has.

If I find anything more on this topic I'll come back and edit it in, but for now it's looking like perhaps a solution using either loops or Index/Match functions also will need to happen to have the data returned in VBA.

I thought about perhaps writing the sheet formula to a cell and then grab that into an array or something but Excel inserts `@` into it now which only returns a single cell result, i.e.

```
Range("J1").Formula = "=FILTER(B1:B9, A1:A9 = D1)"
```

Would return in `J1`:

```
=@FILTER(B1:B9, A1:A9 = D1)
```

Which with our sample data, would only return `2` in `J1` as opposed to the expected/desired `2`, `3` and `4` in `J1:J3`.

I can't work out a way to remove the `@` as it is applied when the function is written to the cell unfortunately, but hopefully any of the above helps someone find a solution.

Comment: The type mismatch is because `Range("RangeOne") = Range("D1")` is equivalent to `Range("RangeOne").Value = Range("D1").Value`, and the left-hand side is a 2D Variant array. Really the 2nd argument of `FILTER` is an array of booleans.... though I kind of repeated myself in this comment as all of this info I already posted elsewhere in comments lol.

Comment: `Range("J1").Formula2 = "=FILTER(B1:B9, A1:A9 = D1)"` should insert the formula without the `@`.... though I think a workaround for OP would just be to `Evaluate` the formula in its normal form.

Comment: Thank you! In the end I didn't figure it out so I ended up solving it with a loop.

Comment: I had no idea about the Evaluate function. It looks like it's exactly what I needed. I'll try it later and see if it works!

Comment: @BigBen yeah I noticed you'd posted that in the other comments but I'd already written it all

Answer (score 2):

Just some comments to help you out.

If you are using the new `FILTER()` function from either a worksheet cell or within some VBA code, the first argument should be a range and the second argument should a a **Boolean array**. *(if you don't enter  something that can evaluate to a Boolean array, VBA may complain the the data type is wrong)*

You would be best served *(in VBA)* if you:

1. explicitly declared a 2 dimensional, column-compatible, Boolean array
2. filled the array
3. used the array in the function call

Here is a super simple example.  Say we want to filter the data from **A1** to **A6** to remove blanks.  We could pick a cell and enter:

```
=FILTER(A1:A6,A1:A6<>"")
```

Looks like:

[image]

Now we want to perform the same activities with a VBA sub and put the result in a block starting with **B9**.  The code:

```
Sub SingleColumn()
    Dim r As Range, wf As WorksheetFunction, i As Long
    Dim arr, s As String, dq As String, boo, rc As Long
    
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Set r = Range("A1:A6")
    rc = r.Rows.Count
    ReDim boo(1 To r.Rows.Count, 1 To 1) As Boolean
    
    i = 1
    For Each rr In r
        If rr.Value = "" Then
            boo(i, 1) = False
        Else
            boo(i, 1) = True
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next rr

    arr = wf.Filter(r, boo)
    
    MsgBox LBound(arr, 1) & "-" & UBound(arr, 1) & vbCrLf & LBound(arr, 2) & "-" & UBound(arr, 2)
    
    Range("B9").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)) = arr
End Sub
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On Excel version 15.0 (2013), I don't see `Application.WorksheetFunction.Filter` (tried with *Show Hidden Members*):

[image]

So maybe this is a newer function in later versions ?

My top Google search directs me to this question ;)

[image]

So, my answer is to avoid the function primarily from the point of view of backwards compatibility.

Alternate code options presented below returning e.g. a `Range` and a `Variant`.

Input:

[image]

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim rngInput As Range
    Dim rngFiltered As Range
    Dim varFiltered As Variant
    Dim varItem As Variant
    
    Set rngInput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:B10")
    
    ' as range
    Debug.Print "' Output as Range"
    Set rngFiltered = MonstersInLevel_AsRange(rngInput, 2, 1, 2)
    Debug.Print "' " & rngFiltered.Address ' expect B5, B6, B8
    Debug.Print "' ---------------"
    
    ' as variant
    Debug.Print "' Output as Variant"
    varFiltered = MonstersInLevel_AsVariant(rngInput, 2, 1, 2)
    For Each varItem In varFiltered
        Debug.Print "' " & varItem ' expect 3, 4, 5
    Next varItem
    Debug.Print "' ---------------"

End Sub

Function MonstersInLevel_AsRange(rngToFilter As Range, _
    ByVal lngLevel As Long, _
    ByVal lngColIxToFilter As Long, _
    ByVal lngColIxForValue As Long) As Range
    
    Dim rngResult As Range
    Dim lngRowIndex As Long
    Dim lngResultIndex As Long
    
    Set rngResult = Nothing
    For lngRowIndex = 1 To rngToFilter.Rows.Count
        If rngToFilter.Cells(lngRowIndex, lngColIxToFilter) = lngLevel Then
            If rngResult Is Nothing Then
                Set rngResult = rngToFilter.Cells(lngRowIndex, lngColIxForValue)
            Else
                Set rngResult = Union(rngResult, rngToFilter.Cells(lngRowIndex, lngColIxForValue))
            End If
        End If
    Next lngRowIndex
       
    Set MonstersInLevel_AsRange = rngResult
    
End Function

Function MonstersInLevel_AsVariant(rngToFilter As Range, _
    ByVal lngLevel As Long, _
    ByVal lngColIxToFilter As Long, _
    ByVal lngColIxForValue As Long) As Variant
    
    Dim varResult As Variant
    Dim lngRowIndex As Long
    Dim lngResultIndex As Long
    
    lngResultIndex = 0
    ReDim varResult(0)
    For lngRowIndex = 1 To rngToFilter.Rows.Count
        If rngToFilter.Cells(lngRowIndex, lngColIxToFilter) = lngLevel Then
            lngResultIndex = lngResultIndex + 1
            ReDim Preserve varResult(1 To lngResultIndex)
            varResult(lngResultIndex) = rngToFilter.Cells(lngRowIndex, lngColIxForValue)
        End If
    Next lngRowIndex
    
    MonstersInLevel_AsVariant = varResult
    
End Function
```

Test output:

```
' Output as Range
' $B$5:$B$6,$B$8
' ---------------
' Output as Variant
' 3
' 5
' 4
' ---------------
```

Comment: This seems like it answers a different question. I don't think OP is looking for how to avoid using FILTER.

Comment: @BigBen noted, and agree my answer is not precisely answering the question. However, the OP in their 2nd comment on the question says **If you guys know any other VBA function that would be more appropriate than Application.WorksheetFunction.Filter I'd be ok.**. Also, the bounty per Scott Craner says **...wanted to see other options.**. So, in these circumstances, I think it's OK to reply with what I would say is a not-not-an-answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Christian Buses answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/65671334/16578424) I wrote a generic function to use the FILTER-function.

It returns a one-dimensional array with the filtered values.

```vb
Public Function getFILTERValuesFromRange(rgResult As Range, rgFilter As Range, varValue As Variant) As Variant

If rgResult.Columns.count > 1 Or rgFilter.Columns.count > 1 Then
    Err.Raise vbObjectError + 512, , "Only ranges with one column are allowed."
ElseIf rgResult.Rows.count <> rgFilter.Rows.count Then
    Err.Raise vbObjectError + 512, , "Both ranges have to be of the same size."
End If

Dim arr1 As Variant
With Application.WorksheetFunction
    arr1 = .filter(rgResult, .XLookup(rgFilter, varValue, True, False))
End With
getFILTERValuesFromRange = getOneDimensionalArrayFromRangeArray(arr1)
End Function

Private Function getOneDimensionalArrayFromRangeArray(arr1 As Variant) As Variant
Dim arr2 As Variant
ReDim arr2(LBound(arr1, 1) To UBound(arr1, 1))

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To UBound(arr1, 1)
    arr2(i) = arr1(i, 1)
Next
getOneDimensionalArrayFromRangeArray = arr2
End Function
```