# Use XLookup for multiple values in range

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I have a list with groups and starting time, where many of the groups have more than one starting time. I have a working vba function that allows me to get the first starting time for every group and write it in another list. How can I use Xlookup in vba to get every time value and not only the first one?
[image]

Here is my vba function:

```
Sub Start_Time()

    Dim UGs(1 To 5) As Long
    Dim ST As String
    

    UGs(1) = 401
    UGs(2) = 402
    UGs(3) = 403
    UGs(4) = 404
    UGs(5) = 405
    
    For Each item In UGs
    
        ST = Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(item, Worksheets("s1").Range("C:C"), Worksheets("s1").Range("B:B"), "", 0)
        Worksheets("s1").Cells(2, 4 + WhereInArray(UGs, item)).Value = ST
    
    Next item
    
End Sub
```

Edit: After editing my code, I now have a filter function which would work just as the filter function in excel, but it does not seem to work that way. Instead of filtering every data, it only gives me the first one, just as my first code.

```
For Each item In UGs
        Dim expr As String
            expr = "=Filter(" & _
               r1.Address & "," & _
               r2.Address & "=" & item & _
               ")"
        Worksheets("s1").Cells(2, 4 + WhereInArray(UGs, item)).Value = Evaluate(expr)
        
    Next item
```

Comment: Instead of `WorksheetFunction.XLookup`, use `WorksheetFunction.Filter`

Comment: If I use the filter function, it outputs the part of my table corresponding to the time. What I want is only the times.

Comment: Now it works when I use the function directly in a cell, but not in vba. The line ```ST = Application.WorksheetFunction.Filter(Worksheets("s1").Range("B:B"), Worksheets("s1").Range("C:C") = item)``` gives me error ```Type Mismatch```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62206989/wrong-data-type-in-worksheetfunction-filter ... you need to create an array of TRUE/FALSE.

Comment: You can use `Evaluate` to sidestep the need for a Boolean array: `Worksheets("s1").Evaluate("Filter("B:B","C:C" & Item & ")")`

Comment: This seems like a good idea, but the line ```ST = Worksheets("s1").Evaluate("Filter("B:B","C:C" & item & ")")``` gives me a syntax error. Don't I need to set the ```"C:C"``` equal to item?

Comment: Yep. Typo on my part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish your output with formulas, VBA or Power query.

If you want to use VBA, I would do the work using native VBA functions and methods.  This will usually be faster than using worksheet functions within VBA that have to access the worksheet.

So, for a VBA solution, I would

- read the data into a VBA array
- organize the data into a Dictionary with

  - the key being each of the UG's
  - the stored item being a collection of the relevant times.
- Then the dictionary can be output to the worksheet in the desired format.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Start_Time()
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim Dict As Object, Col As Collection, sKey As String
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, V As Variant
    
    
'set source and results worksheets and ranges
Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet7")
Set wsRes = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet7")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 20)
    
'read data into vba array for faster processing
With wsSrc
    vSrc = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
End With

'collect data into dictionary for organizing
Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    sKey = vSrc(I, 2)
    If Not Dict.Exists(sKey) Then
        Set Col = New Collection
        Col.Add vSrc(I, 1)
        Dict.Add Key:=sKey, Item:=Col
    Else
        Dict(sKey).Add vSrc(I, 1)
    End If
Next I

'organize output
'size results array
'num of rows
I = 0
For Each V In Dict
    I = IIf(I > Dict(V).Count, I, Dict(V).Count)
Next V

ReDim vRes(0 To I, 1 To Dict.Count)

'populate each column

'Sort the keys
Dim al As Object
Set al = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
For Each V In Dict.Keys
    al.Add V
Next V

al.Sort

J = 0
For Each V In al
    J = J + 1
    vRes(0, J) = V
    For I = 1 To Dict(V).Count
        vRes(I, J) = Dict(V)(I)
    Next I
Next V
    
'write to the worksheet and format
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(rowsize:=UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, columnsize:=UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .Resize(rowsize:=.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(rowoffset:=1).NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss AM/PM"
    .Style = "Output"
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With
    
End Sub
```

**Source Data**

[image]

**Results**

[image]

But my preferred "code method" of doing this would be as a Pivot Table using Power Query; and a custom function that allows doing a Pivot without aggregation.

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm
- Also you must add the custom function as a "blank query" and rename it `fnPivotAll

**M Code**

```
let

//Change table name in next line to the Actual table name in your workbook
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="groupTable"]}[Content],

//set the data types. Note we must set datatype of the UG column to Text for pivoting
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Start", type time}, {"UG", Text.Type}}),

//call the custom function for pivot without aggregation
    pivotAll = fnPivotAll(#"Changed Type", "UG","Start"),

//set the resultant data types
    typeIt = Table.TransformColumnTypes(pivotAll, List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(pivotAll), each {_, type time}))
in
    typeIt
```

**M Code for Custom Function**
*be sure to rename this `fnPivotAll`*

```
//credit: Cam Wallace  https://www.dingbatdata.com/2018/03/08/non-aggregate-pivot-with-multiple-rows-in-powerquery/

(Source as table,
    ColToPivot as text,
    ColForValues as text)=> 

let
     PivotColNames = List.Buffer(List.Sort(List.Distinct(Table.Column(Source,ColToPivot)))),
     #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Source, PivotColNames, ColToPivot, ColForValues, each _),
 
    TableFromRecordOfLists = (rec as record, fieldnames as list) =>
    
    let
        PartialRecord = Record.SelectFields(rec,fieldnames),
        RecordToList = Record.ToList(PartialRecord),
        Table = Table.FromColumns(RecordToList,fieldnames)
    in
        Table,
 
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Pivoted Column", "Values", each TableFromRecordOfLists(_,PivotColNames)),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",PivotColNames),
    #"Expanded Values" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Values", PivotColNames)
in
    #"Expanded Values"
```

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to using VBA to write formulas I am not really a true believer. So, here is a solution that writes the results. Perhaps the gist of this approach is in that one distributes the list of original data to the output range instead of picking a value for each cell in the latter as worksheet functions would require. Perhaps it's an advantage that no data in the list can be left excluded.

```
Sub WriteSchedule()
    ' 264

    Dim Source      As Range            ' data range
    Dim Data        As Variant
    Dim Headers     As Range            ' destination captions
    Dim Target      As Range            ' destination
    Dim Ct          As Long             ' Target column
    Dim Arr         As Variant          ' working array
    Dim R           As Long             ' loop counter: rows
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")               ' change name to suit
        ' columns must be of equal length
        Set Source = .Range(.Cells(3, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
        Data = Source.Value
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' this presumes that output will be on another sheet
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")               ' change name to suit
        Arr = Application.Unique(Source.Columns(2).Value)
        Set Headers = .Range("E2")           ' anchor cell: change to suit
        Set Headers = Headers.Resize(1, UBound(Arr))
        With Headers
            .Value = Application.Transpose(Arr)
            .Sort Key1:=.Cells(1), Order1:=xlAscending, Orientation:=xlLeftToRight
            Set Target = Headers.Offset(1).Resize(UBound(Data))
        End With
        
        For R = 1 To UBound(Data)
            Ct = Application.Match(Data(R, 2), Headers, 0) + Headers.Column - 1
            With .Cells(.Rows.Count, Ct).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .Value = Data(R, 1)
                .NumberFormat = "hh:mm AM/PM"
            End With
        Next R
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The code looks more voluminous than it really is because it does a lot of things not originally planned, such as preparing the destination table to match the source data. Note that I tested it with source and destination on the same sheet but the code design intends to permit them to be on different tabs.

Comment: I changed my code to evalute a filter function but it does not seem to work the same way as if I enter it in excel. When I use it in my function, it only outputs the first time, but the function in excel outputs all of the times.

Comment: This doesn't look like a comment on my solution. You may have intended to add it below your question. However, since you are here, please try my code.  It will give you the result you want on first try with no ifs and buts. All you need is a worksheet like the one you posted a picture of, its name *Sheet1* and the two columns in A and B.