Count distinct dates in range based on start and end date criteria
In a worksheet I have a flat-file structure with a column for dates, followed by additional columns for other variables.
In VBA, I need to be able to count the number of unique dates in Column A (which has a named range of "Date") and pass this count to the VBA code.
I have attempted to use the following VBA, but I'm getting a runtime error 13, type mismatch.
RawStartDate is a named range (single cell) in excel date format, i.e. 01/01/2024, as is RawEndDate.
Dim RawDistinctDates as Long 
RawDistinctDates = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Application.WorksheetFunction.Unique(Application.WorksheetFunction.Filter(Range("Date"), (Range("Date") >= Range("RawStartDate")) * (Range("Date") <= Range("RawEndDate")))))
MsgBox RawDistinctDates

I'm open to a pure VBA method, instead of only using WorksheetFunction.
Why am I not able to get the variable to pass the count?

see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62206989/wrong-data-type-in-worksheetfunction-filter

Thanks. Are there any notable drawbacks to using Application.Evaluate("=COUNT(UNIQUE(FILTER(Date,(Date>=RawStartDate)*(Date<=RawEndDate))))") instead?

Nope.  That is a good option.

Short, easy and fast solution is
Option Explicit

Function CountUniqueDatesBetween(rng As Range, lb&, ub&) As Long
  Dim a, i&, j&, pv&, al&
  a = Application.Sort(rng.Value2): j = 0
  For i = 1 To al
    If a(i, 1) >= lb Then Exit For
  Next
  pv = a(i, 1) - 1
  For i = i To al
    If a(i, 1) > ub Then Exit For
    If a(i, 1) > pv Then
      pv = a(i, 1): j = j + 1
    End If
  Next
  CountUniqueDatesBetween = j
End Function

